# SharePoint Document Link Content Type - Pointing to documents on a file share?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010

I have a large number of documents present in a file share that I would like to add as document links in a DocLib instead of uploading them all into SharePoint.  Unfortunately, the OOB Document Link content type only accepts URLs beginning with http: or https:… no file://

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You can "trick" the system into allowing URLs that do not begin with "HTTP" or "HTTPS". 
This is how: The screen that first appears when you create a new "Link to Document" prompts you for a name and URL. This screen has a script that checks entries to verify that they have the "HTTP" or "HTTPS" in the URL. To bypass this script you just enter a dummy URL into the field (i.e. http://www.google.com). On the next screen you are prompted to enter the meta-data for the link, at which time you can add the file share URL over the dummy URL you entered earlier. 
It might not be the most "graceful" solution, but it does work. Using this method you can easily link to file shares from SharePoint.

~Erich Zann

Answer (score 0):

What kind of functionality you expect from the content type. Maybe something based on generic list item can suffice, with a simple text field to hold the link?

Comment: Great question... I had considered that.  The beauty of the Document Link content type is that it shows up in a document library just like a real document... it has the appropriate icon (just with a small shortcut arrow), the contents (elsewhere on the intranet wherever the source document lives) are indexed and show up in search results... It is just like having the real document in my library, but with the benefit of not taking up space against my quota (other than a few kilobytes).

Comment: I see what you mean. I would do the following:
1. Create a new content type, inheriting from Document Link CT, replace the URL field with a text field.
2. Develop a custom NewLink.aspx (this is the page where you fail to enter the path). It's possible that you could just copy the existing one and remove the input validation, but I doubt it. The page should create a new item of your new content type
3. Attach the new page to the new CT (in the document template field of the content type, exactly as it's set up in the Document Link CT)
4. You can wrap the whole thing in a solution (WSP)